# How to make vertical tabbar on landscape orientation in sencha touch2

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a horizontal tabbar at bottom.I need to  change bootom horizontal tabbar to vertical tabbar in landscape orientation. I have gone many articles but they are explained only for bottom and top tabbar position. **i didn't not got about vertical tabbar position in landscape orientation. Is it possible to achieve in sencha touch2?**. Any one can tell me how to acieve this one .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well in a normal tabpanel code just add

```
tabBar: {
    docked:'left'
},
```

But you will need to work on the css a bit as the buttons don't look proper.